# Jenkins configuration with SSL issue

Tags: ssl, jenkins

I getting some weird issue with SSL configuration on Jenkins CI. After disabling SSLv3 on Windows Server 2008 where we host our Jenkins, we're unable to open web page when we add https arguments to Jenkins configuration:

```
--httpsKeyStore="D:\apps\jenkins\secrets\keystore2 --httpsKeyStorePassword=*****
```

With that arguments in java command, when we're trying to reach webpage Firefox gives us this error:

```
An error occurred during a connection to xxx.com:8080. Cannot communicate securely with peer: no common encryption algorithm(s). Error code: SSL_ERROR_NO_CYPHER_OVERLAP
```

But when we remove those arguments, and Jenkins will create its own SSL cert, everything works ok, but Jenkins is using its own self-generated certificate and we want to use our own.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I don't have to use port 443 for SSL. HTTPS and port are configured ok with --https=8080 in Jenkins java command, the setup was working properly until we had to disable SSLv3 in Windows Server 2008 registry due to vulnerability warnings from our security officer.

Answer (score -1):

Jenkins community has identified this issue. There is an JIRA for this particular issue which can be tracked at https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-56747?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Aall-tabpanel.

A possible solution was proposed at https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/216526298-Disabling-Specific-Ciphers-In-Jenkins. One would need to override jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms and set it's value as following:

```
  jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=RC4, DES-CBC3-SHA keySize < 256, SSLv3, DSA, RSA keySize < 2048
```